# Keep track of macro expansion

Tags: c++, macros, boost-preprocessor

I want to keep track of macro expansion - how many times the macro has been expanded and what are the args when expansion happened.

For example,

I have a macro might look like this:

```
#define mymacro(x) int x
```

and in my code I have something like this:

```
mymacro(a);
mymacro(b);
```

in the end of the preprocessor expansion (oh yeah, is there a way to make a specific macro to become the last to expand?), I would like to know how many times mymacro has been used and what are the args passed. In this case, it would be 2 times, and args would be a and b.

I was investigating boost-preprocessor lib. They have BOOST_PP_ARRAY, but I don't know how to make it "static", so that I can use it in later.

I found something in the BOOST_PP_COUNTER. It looks like the BOOST_PP_COUNTER is something that can maintain its state in preprocessor phrase. But I am still unclear how to do what I wanted.

Comment: This could be done by adding a line to the macro that outputs a compiler message, if your compiler supports that.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I am using Clang

Comment: It's not immediately clear to me, but you are talking past inspection of what's happening and want the result (ie what it's been invoked with, etc...) to be available at preprocessing time so that you can do something with it, right ?

Comment: yes, that's what I want to do

Comment: I hope you're not expecting this count to be maintained across compilation units...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
#include <iostream>

int m_counter = 0;
const char *m_arguments[32] = { 0 };

#define COUNT_M(a) m_arguments[m_counter++] = #a;
#define M(a) COUNT_M(a) int a

int main()
{
    M(x);
    M(y);

    for (int i = 0; i < m_counter; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "m_arguments[" << i << "] = \"" << m_arguments[i] << "\"\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm... in this case M(x) and M(y) needs to be invoked at runtime, in order to work. My marcos are callbacks, so it's not nessaccerily to be invoked. Anyway to do this in compile time?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what your ultimate goal is, but you can track the number of scans(not the number of expansions) using an active argument. An active argument expands each time that it is scanned by the preprocessor. For example,

```
#define EMPTY()

#define A(n) \
    A_INDIRECT EMPTY()()(BOOST_PP_INC(n)) 

#define A_INDIRECT() A

#define X(arg) arg
#define Y(arg) X(arg)
#define Z(arg) Y(arg)

   A(0)   // A_INDIRECT()(1)
X( A(0) ) // A_INDIRECT()(2)
Y( A(0) ) // A_INDIRECT()(3)
Z( A(0) ) // A_INDIRECT()(4)
```

Each invocation of A is subjected to a different number of scans, which causes the results to be different each time.

Macros can't effect the global state. The only other way to achieve some sort of state is to use recursion. Remember, macros don't expand recursively, so the preprocessor keeps tracks of this state. Its the only "global" state that can be affected by macros. However, it can be difficult to control. Macros have to be forced to expand at a certain recursion level with a macro for each level, and some form of binary searching is required to read the "state" efficiently.